# What is the easiest way to color part of a picture

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I want to make a website where you can customize a braclet, you can pick up to 6 colors. The user should be able to see the final product before ordering. If i have a black and white image of the product what is the easiest way to color the picture. I will be using react for frontend and nodejs for backend.
Is it easier to use WebGL?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40444657/9868549

Comment: I will check it right now thank you